# Simple python sqlite code cannot work. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have this simple python sqlite code to execute a simple SQL statement.

```
import sqlite3
db_pathname = "./data/db.sqlite3"
sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_pathname)
sqlite_cur = sqlite_conn.cursor()

sql_statement = """INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_infos (code, name) VALUES('XL2.SO', 'AGOS Pte')"""
sqlite_cur.execute(sql_statement)
```

I do not see a new record being added to the sqlite database after running the code. However, if I run the SQL statement manually using a sqlite tool called DB Browser, a new record is added.

I am using python 3.6 and sqlite3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [commit the changes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit).

```
sqlite_cur.execute(sql_statement)
sqlite_conn.commit()
```

Comment: or can add  `isolation_level=None`  like this `sqlite3.connect('sqlitedb.db', isolation_level=None)`. Which does auto commit